# How to override ToolbarItem on iOS 16?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, toolbar, ios16

With iOS 16, the toolbar and toolbarItem are working differently. On iOS 14/15, when adding two toolbars one after another, the second one overrides the first one. With iOS 16, the content from the second one extends the content of the first one. What I tried was to set ids for toolbar and toolbarItem hoping will have the same behaviour as on iOS 14/15 but it's not really working.

Desired behaviour is the one from iOS 14/15 and it looks like this:

[image]

Current behaviour for iOS 16:

[image]

This is my code which is working ok for iOS 14/15:

```
struct RootView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Text("Hello, World!").padding()
                .navigationTitle("navigation title")
                .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
                .toolbar(id: "toolbar_id") {
                    ToolbarItem(id: "toolbaritem_id", placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                        Button("Button 1") {
                            print("Pressed Button 1")
                        }
                    }
                }
                .toolbar(id: "toolbar_id") {
                    ToolbarItem(id: "toolbaritem_id", placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                        Button("Button 2") {
                            print("Pressed Button 2")
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
        .navigationViewStyle(.stack)
    }
}
```

Comment: So you supposed that the code was doing a specific behaviour with wrong code. If you want multiple button you have to use HStack inside toolbaritem. In your case I don’t think the behaviour can be defined for sure. If you want override you should find another approach using Boolean or enum coming from your model to be sure to display what you expect.

Comment: @PtitXav I simplified a lot the code to expose the problem on iOS 16, in my project there is no direct relation between the first toolbar and the last one, they don't share models or anything

Comment: Ok. Did you use same iPhone for new simulator?

Comment: @PtitXav, yes same simulator